# Android Studio SDK location

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

I see there a lot of similar topics pertaining to this issue but I did not find a solution for me among those posts. I just installed Android Studio v0.8.14 and it won't let me create a new project because I do not have an SDK path specified. For the life of me I cannot find where that path should be. I see many people have it located in C:/Android or someplace similar, however the only Android files I have are on my desktop in the extracted folder that came in the .zip. All paths inside that folder do not qualify as an appropriate SDK location, according to Android Studio. Am I being completely ridiculous and missing the obvious?

Comment: As of today (2015-10-01), the standard download in @RandollREVERS solution comes with the sdk (but you can also use that link to find the sdk standalone package). I needed to create the path variable for it (suprised Android didn't do this for me) after downloading the studio and then another path variable for the platform-tools directory where the `adb` command is located. Each time the sdk package is downloaded, the entire folder is enumerated under your `Android` install directory (`\sdk`, `\sdk1`...).  CrandellWS 's solution pointed me to my existing directory I didn't know existed.

Comment: You can set the path manually from: %Home%\.AndroidStudio2.1\config\options\jdk.table.xml

Comment: I don't know why for the problem narration so many credits? when solution finder has to be credited. This issue everyone come across in Andriod, so no need of increasing credit of questioner.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Download the SDK from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/ to C:\android-sdk\.

Then when you launch Android Studio again, it will prompt you for the SDK path just point it to: C:\android-sdk\.

Update: new download location, https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools

Comment: That link points to Android Studio, not to the SDK. Android Studio appears to hide the SDK somewhere in the user's AppData directory.

Comment: Any luck locating this?

Comment: That link points to Android Studio, not to the SDK. any update?

Comment: The SDK download is on the page linked, scroll down and its under `command line tools only` (but not necessary because it comes with Android Studio).

Comment: link based on @jackw11111's comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/#command-tools

Answer (score 167):

For Mac/OSX the default location is `/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk`.

Comment: Library only appears under <username> when navigated to through terminal. Going to that same location using finder renders it invisible for some reason.

Comment: Finder hides the user home as standard. But can either use the menus, `GO -> Home` or just use the shortcut `Cmd+Shft+H`. Once in Home you will find Library and then Android.

Comment: If you find this question and are trying to just launch the SDK manager (or AVD manager) without launching all of Android Studio you can also launch a terminal prompt and type `open ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android`

Comment: You can use `CMD+SHIFT+.` (period) for revealing hidden folders. I couldn't see Library either. That solved it for me.

Comment: right click under <username> there's an option to show Library folder. This solved it for me

Answer (score 89):

Android Studio on Windows 8:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe
```

(in username : please enter valid username)

Install it and restart your Android Studio.

The above steps are similar for win 7 and also same for eclipse.

Update: Windows 10 (similar steps) - pointed out by RBT

Comment: AppData folder is hidden by default so you need to make it visible first then you can access it.

Comment: The path is exactly the same for my Visual Studio installation (on Windows 10) as well which now supports cross platform apps using Xamarin.

Comment: You don't need to make AppData visible, you can simply type in the explorer address bar `%localappdata%` to go to `AppData/Local` or `%appdata%` to go to `AppData/Roaming`

Answer (score 72):

This is the sdk path Android Studio installed for me:
"C:\Users\<username>\appdata\local\android\sdk"

I'm running windows 8.1.

You can find the path going into Android Studio -> Configure -> SDK Manager -> On the top left it should say SDK Path.

I don't think it's necessary to install the sdk separately, as the default option for Android Studio is to install the latest sdk too.

Comment: Thats where mine was too. Using Windows 7 and latest Android Studio as of today 2/23/2017.

Comment: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\Sdk

Answer (score 53):

I had forgot where the sdk location was installed to so what I did was open Android Studio and selected `Settings` then used the following submenu

Current 1/1/2017:**`Tools -> SDK Manager`**

[image: Latest edition]

*outdate:* <strike>`Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK`</strike>

There the sdk location was listed as `Android SDK Location`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a difference in operating system, or Android Studio version, but on 12/24/2015 in Ubuntu, this information is under `Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager`

Comment: I had it wrong there, and thats why i needed the path. The other solutions are better ones

Comment: Now it's in Tools -> SDK Manager

Comment: Note that the location in the settings tree isn't outdated, the `Tools -> SDK Manager` menu item in the main window is just a shortcut to it. You can go to the settings location even from the small launcher window you get when no project is open by clicking on the `Configuration` button with the gear icon.

Answer (score 24):

- Linux (Ubuntu 18.4)

`/home/<USER_NAME>/Android/Sdk`

- windows (8.1)

`C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

(AppData folder is hidden, check folder properties first)

- macOS (Sierra 10.12.6)

`/Users/<USER_NAME>/Library/Android/sdk`

Comment: This answer is the best as it provides info for all platforms. Should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 22):

> **macOS** (Catalina or Mojave or Sierra):

After installing Android Studio (3.6+ or 2.3.x),
by default

sdk path: "*/Users/< username >/Library/Android/sdk*"

**Remember:**
may be
*Library*  folder is hidden.
To make it visible:-  Hit `Command+shift+.` OR
Open Terminal and type "chflags nohidden ~/Library/" then hit return.

> **windows**:

After installing Android Studio,
by default

sdk path: "*C:\Users< username >\AppData\Local\Android\sdk*"

**Remember:**
by default
AppData folder is hidden, make it visible first.

Comment: Yes, and `command + shift + . ` is the shortcut to show hidden files.

Comment: for mac os Catalina (10.15.5) It was `/Users/<my_user_name>/Library/Android` don't forget to press `Command+shift+.`

Comment: sdk path can be modified as `%appdata%\..\Local\Android\sdk`, Instead of `C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

Answer (score 15):

Start **Android Studio** and select **Configure** --> **SDK Manager**

[image]

Then, check the path of **Android SDK**

[image]

If you can't find the SDK location, you may want to **[download it](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads)**. Just scroll down to near end of the download page and select the Android SDK with respect to your OS.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\

The location I found it in for Windows 8.1. I think the default SDK folder. AppData is a hidden folder, so you will not locate it unless you type it in once you get into your C:\Users\ folder.

Answer (score 8):

For Mac users running:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Select Android Studio -> Preferences -> System Settings -> Android
   SDK
3. Your SDK location will be specified on the upper right side of the
   screen under [Android SDK Location]

I'm running Android Studio 2.2.3

Comment: Yes, it will prompt you to a download wizard. For mac

Answer (score 5):

When i upgraded i just moved my SDK to my user folder C:\Users\Nick\Android-SDK and updated my path in Android Studio. Worked like a charm.

EDIT: (More detail) - My SDK was originally inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk, I just Cut and Paste the entire \sdk folder into C:\Users\Nick\Android-SDK, then set it inside Android Studio to the new location.

Comment: I am fairly new to programming so excuse my somewhat half witlessness, but I do not have Android in my program files. I am unsure where my original SDK would/should be or if I need to download it separately from Android Studio.

Comment: No problem, so you installed Android Studio. Did you try going to "configure" from the main menu, and openeing up the SDK Manager? You can download SDK's from there. Try that and see what happens.

Comment: I am currently in configure > project defaults > project structure. The left column just has SDK Location and my path for the location is blank. However, I don't see where I can download SDK's.


EDIT: I backed up and I see SDK Manager, however, it is grayed out.

Comment: Did you see in that list of items where you clicked "Project Defaults" at the top it has "SDK Manager"? Try going into there and downloading some of the latest API's. That should make you a folder which you can then point to.

Comment: Yeah I see the SDK Manager but it is grayed out and I cannot select it.

Comment: Ahh ok. Yeah you need to download the SDK directly then, See Randoll Revers answer, just download the SDK manually and extract/save it to your user directory. Then you can go back into Project Defaults like you did before and point it to the SDK directory. You should be good to go then!

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu users running:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Select Android Studio -> Settings -> Android SDK   or
   Android Studio -> Project structure -> SDK location or to open Project structure shortcut is (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)
3. Your SDK location will be specified on the upper right side of the screen under [Android SDK Location]

Comment: This appears to just be the same answer as [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41595205/2756409) from over a year prior, with just "Ubuntu users" swapped in for "Mac users"

Answer (score 4):

Default path in Windows

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\
```

Answer (score 4):

Linux 2021, after installed follow these steps!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your project is open click on `Gradle Scripts >local.properties(SDK LOCATION)`, open it and there is the location of `sdk` with name

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\shiva\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

**Note don't forget the replace `\\` to `\` before coping the things(sdk location)**

Answer (score 2):

Open the Preferences window by clicking File > Settings (on Mac, Android Studio > Preferences).

In the left panel, click Appearance & Behavior > Android SDK.

You will see the path

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

This is the right path, if you looking up for `sdkmanager`.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK is in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Answer (score 1):

**(MAC Users)** To find sdk Location in **Android Arctic Fox**:
File >> Project Structure>> SDK Location.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Using windows 7 64bits

C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 - when upgrading from AS 2.x to 3.01

AS has the SDK directory name changed from .../sdk to .../Sdk

Because I kept my original settings this caused an issue.
Changed back to lowercase and all working!

Answer (score 0):

AndroidStudioFrontScreenI simply double clicked the Android dmg install file that I saved on the hard drive and when the initial screen came up I dragged the icon for Android Studio into the Applications folder, now I know where it is!!! Also when you run it, be sure to right click the Android Studio while on the Dock and select "Options" -> "Keep on Dock". Everything else works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create a new folder in your android studio parent directory folder. Name it sdk or whatever you want.
Select that folder from the drop down list when asked.
Thats what solves it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted solution but it didn't resolve the issue for me.

I had already installed Android Studio 2-3 years ago, but I uninstalled it at some point. Installing the latest version was giving me an error. I did multiple uninstalls/reinstallations, but the issue persisted.

I found an SDK was available on my machine in %LocalAppData%. I opened the environment variable and deleted all the references of Android like Android Home /Path. I performed the uninstallation of Android Studio and then reinstalled.

This time it worked and installed properly; it is even downloading the other SDK-related files.

Answer (score 0):

*If you are working on React native,please make sure you have installed these tools because I was missing and it resolved my issue*
[image: Necessory tolls for installations]
[React Native doc for installation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Answer (score 0):

I found this a couple of minutes back.

What renders the location unuseful is the fact that it is neither empty nor has the sdk.
One of the conditions needs to be met for the folder.

So, try this:

1. On Windows, go to **Control Panel** and search for 'show hidden folders and files'.
   You will find a "Folders" option. On the submenu, you will see "Show hidden files and
   folders".
   [The options look like this.][1]
2. Refer this image.
   [Click the option shown in the picture][2]
3. Click apply and ok.
4. Go to the location i.e. some location in appdata, or the location your android sdk was
   about to be installed in. The location should be visible now.
   Go to it and delete everything inside. (Don't delete the sdk folder, just the contents
   inside it )
5. Go to android sdk manager and select the same location again. The error should vanish.
   Happy installation!

In other words, this error only pops up if you had a previous failed installation.

If you're unable to do it still, hit me up at twitter @Vishma Pratim Das and I will be happy to assist you.
Thanks.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6P8S.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeRUZ.png

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Android Studio and has the same problem.

Banged my head for a few hours and found the solution - it's retarded.

So I installed Android Studio but when it asked me for the config folder, I provided the one from my IntelliJ. Well, turns out that stop the Android Studio setup and I had no SDK. Going to their site the SDK is nowhere to be found. It's not on any of the links from the other answers either.

My solution was to use a different folder for Android Studio. That ran the setup wizard and downloaded the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing what worked for me in hopes that it helps someone else.

My issue was that my SDK was not installed together with the Android Studio IDE for some reason. How I managed to trigger the SDK installation was by going to File > Settings on Android Studio, then typing "sdk" in the searchbar. If your android sdk location is empty, click on "edit" right next to it and it should immediately prompt installation for your sdk.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, do not move/put android sdk under /usr/lib/ directory because it will only have read permissions and other libraries cannot be downloaded.

Answer (score -3):

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe

check this location in windows