# Set ANDROID_HOME environment variable in mac

Tags: android, environment-variables, java-home

I am new in developing native app using Salesforce SDK. I tried to create android project from command line using forcedroid tool but there is problem in setting environment variable named ANDROID_HOME.

But i don't know how to set this variable.

I am attaching screenshot to describe my problem correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Open the terminal and type :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/ADT/sdk
```

Add this to the PATH environment variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

If the terminal doesn't locate the added path(s) from the **.zshrc**, please run this command

`source ~/.zshrc`

Hope it works to you!

Comment: When I open a new terminal, echo $ANDROID_HOME shows me empty again.

Comment: Check this [link](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path/14821/15)

Comment: I've done that many times without hope but when I typed `source ~/.bash_profile` after setting the paths, it solved my issue.

Comment: Why not **/.bashrc**?

Comment: As this answer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62102594/735226) states if you are on Cataline upward, you have to use `.zprofile` instead of `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 280):

To make it **permanent on your system** and the variable keep working after close the terminal, ou after a restart use:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Add lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
```

Reopen terminal and check if it worked:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

If you use `Oh My Zsh` as terminal, you must add these lines to `~/.zshrc` instead `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: I have to use the `source` command every time I open a new tab. How can I make it so that ANDROID_HOME is always available?

Comment: for MAC OS: Android SDK PATH help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30402196/5589073

Comment: ANDROID_HOME: /Users/<MAC USER NAME>/Library/Android/sdk

Comment: Nice answer.
add more if your don't know path sdk your can check it

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532063/finding-android-sdk-on-mac-and-adding-to-path

Comment: Why not write:
`export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk` ? :)

Comment: @BurkeHolland, You can add those lines in ~/.zshrc instead ~/.bash_profile I guess

Answer (score 55):

The above answer is correct. Works really well. There is also quick way to do this.

1. Open command prompt
2. Type - **echo export "ANDROID_HOME=/Users/yourName/Library/Android/sdk" >> ~/.bash_profile**

   Thats's it.
3. Close your terminal.
4. Open it again.
5. Type - **echo $ANDROID_HOME** to check if the home is set.

Comment: My home is still not set, it shows me empty even after doing above steps, I am using Sierra Mac.

Comment: Works great for Mac Catalina echo export "ANDROID_HOME=/Users/appstream/Library/Android/sdk" >> ~/.zshrc

Comment: I am on Sonoma and can't set ANDROID_HOME, always empty

Comment: @MikeFlynn Did you restart your terminal or call `source .zshrc` after making your changes?

Answer (score 36):

If you try to run "adb devices" OR any other command and it says something like

```
zsh: command not found adb
```

It tells that you are using zsh shell and /.bash_profile won't work as it should. You will have to execute bash_profile everytime with `source ~/.bash_profile` command when you open terminal, and it isn't permanent.

To fix this run:

`nano ~/.zshrc`

[Terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYkL1.png)

and then paste following commands at the end of the file

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/{YourName}/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
```

> NOTE: You can find Android Home url from Android Studio > Preferences
> System Settings > Android SDK > Android SDK Location textbox

To save it, hit Ctrl + X, type Y to save and then enter to keep the file name as it is.

Restart the terminal and try your commands again.

Answer (score 26):

If you are setting up the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable on macOS Catalina, `.bash_profile` is no longer Apple's default shell, and it won't persist your path variables. Use `.zprofile` instead and follow the environment setup instructions in react-native documentation or others. .bash_profile will keep creating new file which won't make the path permanent or persist on closing the terminal on your system path.

To create a new path just do this in macOS Big Sur:

1. `sudo touch ~/.zshrc`
2. `sudo nano ~/.zshrc`
3. export all the path
4. crtl + x and save
5. `source ~/.zshrc`
6. Check with echo $PATH

Answer (score 20):

Based on Abraham Mayowa Oluwasina answer provided above is the correct one.
MacOS Catalina and later, .bash_profile is no longer apple's default shell and it won't persist in your path variables instead use .zprofile instead.

In root directory,

```
touch .zprofile
open -e .zprofile
```

Add the following to file,
Android:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Java:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.15.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Save and exit

To activate

```
source ~/. profile
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

Answer (score 8):

The only solution worked for me was @Tiago Gouvêa answer, after adding it android and emulator commands worked fine, but sdkmanager command was not working so I have added one extra line to his solution:

`nano ~/.bash_profile`

Add lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/YOUR_PATH_TO/android-sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 6):

As a noob I was struggling a lot with setting up the variable.I was creating copies of .bash_profile files, the text in file was not saving etc ..

So I documented the the steps that worked for me. It is simple and foolproof( but little lengthy ) way to do it ✌

**Step1.** Go to **Finder** >**Go**(on top) , click on **users**, then your **user account** 
you will see something like this :

{https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e9qX.png}

**Step2.** Now hold down ⌘ + ⇧ + . (dot) , this will now display hidden files and folders. It will look something like this:

{https://i.stack.imgur.com/apOoO.png}

PS: If the ⌘ + ⇧ +. does not work, please look up the keyboard shortcut relevant for your Mac Operating system name

**Step3.**

***Scenario A* :If `.bash_profile` already exists**

**Step3.A.1** :Double click the .bash_profile. It should open up with **TextEdit** ( or alternatively right click >open with >TextEdit)

**Step3.A.2** : Paste the variable text in the .bash_profile file using ⌘ + V

**Step3.A.3** :Save the .bash_profile file using ⌘ + S

***Scenario B* :If `.bash_profile` does NOT exist** 
This is kind silly way of doing it , but it worked perfectly for noob like me

**Step3.B.1** : Download free **BBEdit** text editor which is pretty light weight. Whats special about this editor is that it lets you save file that starts with ". "

**Step3.B.2** : Create a new file

**Step3.B.3** : Save the file in your account folder . A warning will pop up , which looks something like this:

{https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLZmL.png}

Click **Use"."** button. Then the blank .bash_profile file will be saved

**Step3.B.4** : Paste the variable text in the .bash_profile file using ⌘ + V

**Step3.B.5** :Save the .bash_profile file using ⌘ + S

**Step 4:** Last and final step is to check if the above steps worked.
Open the bash and type **`echo $ANDROID_HOME`**

Your ANDROID_HOME variable should be now set.

Answer (score 6):

**Open Terminal**

```
nano ~/.bash_profile


export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/qss/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH

Control+S to save
Control+X to exit
Y to save changes
Update changes in terminal
source ~/.bash_profile

Validate Path:
echo $PATH

Confirm if all okay:
adb devices
```

Answer (score 5):

```
source ~/.bash_profile
export ANDROID_HOME=/YOUR_PATH_TO/android-sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Comment: Include explanation and proper formatting to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

For mac OS monterey 12.0.1

Default terminal is .zsh

**Step 1:**
open terminal then type this command.

```
nano ~/.zsh
```

**Step 2:**
copy below command and past it.

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/{your sdk path}/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH`
```

**Step3:**  Press command ^X then press Y  then press enter

**Stpe4:** Close terminal and reopen it Type below command:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

You can find your path. That's it !

Answer (score 3):

MacOS

add this string in file ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/<userlogin>/Library/Android/sdk"
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the path of ANDROID_HOME  > You have to open terminal and enter the below cmd.

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

After that paste below paths in base profile file and save it

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk 
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, get the Android SDK location in Android Studio :
Android Studio
-> Preferences
-> Appearance & Behaviour
-> System Settings
-> Android SDK
-> Android SDK Location

Then execute the following commands in terminal

> export ANDROID_HOME=*Paste here your SDK location*
>
> export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin

It is done.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type **touch .bash_profile** and press Enter
3. Now Type **open .bash_profile** and again press Enter
4. A textEdit file will be opened
5. Now type **export ANDROID_HOME="Users/Your_User_Name/Library/Android/sdk"**
6. Then in next line type **export PATH="${PATH}:/$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools:/$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin"**
7. Now save this .bash_profile file
8. Close the Terminal

To verify if Path is set successfully open terminal again and type adb if adb version and other details are displayed that means path is set properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this after add **ANDROID_HOME** on your Environment Variable, work well on my mac

`flutter config --android-sdk ANDROID_HOME`

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem on mac 10.14
`brew install android-sdk`

Answer (score 0):

If using fish, append these lines to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`:

```bash
# Setting Android Studio Path for fish
set -x ANDROID_HOME $HOME/Library/Android/sdk
set -x PATH "$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools" "$PATH"
set -x PATH "$ANDROID_HOME/tools" "$PATH"
set -x PATH "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin" "$PATH"
set -x PATH "$ANDROID_HOME/emulator" "$PATH"
```

After saving the changes, restart fish or type `source ~/.config/fish/config.fish`.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOs ventura and android studio giraffe:

**Step 1:**
For sdk path:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Go To Tools tab from top menu
3. Go SDK manager
4. In top there is field name *Androd SDK Location*, you can copy it.

**Step 2:**

Open ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc

**Step 3**

Paste these commands at the end of the file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/{your sdk path}/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$PATH
```

**Step 4:**

Save the file and make sure to close all terminal open for that folder

**Step 5:**

Open terminal again and type this command to verify *Android_Home* path:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

if this command not showing anything it means Android_Home not add properly, you need to check and make sure that you save the file properly.