# SDK Location not found

Tags: android, git

I created recently a new local repo and pulled some code to it, from our remote repository.

When i open the project, I receive a message in console:

```
Gradle sync failed: SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
     Consult IDE log for more details
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296237/set-android-home-environment-variable-in-mac) to set the environment variable (Im in a Mac) and checked my local.properties:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk
```

So, both things are settled up, and I am still getting this error. Ive searched, but no solution worked for me.

Any help? Thank you.

EDIT:

This only happens with one project. The rest of the projects works perfectly.

Comment: how did you fixed it ??

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio:

1. Open your project navigator
2. Pick the root item, right click --> Open Module Settings.
3. In the Android SDK location field, make sure the correct path is selected (up to the sdk folder). See example below:

[image]

Comment: Its there, was the first thing i checked

Comment: Have you tried restarting Android Studio and/or invalidating caches (File --> Invalidate Caches)?

Comment: also, try changing sdk.dir to android.dir in your local.properties file, and make sure it's at your project's root.

Comment: Did both things...no luck

Comment: If the SDK path is correct, remove `/sdk` part from `Android SDK Location` path. Then click on `apply` (or ok). gradle should start resyncing... and then the error should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried the above comments. Later on the error changed to

"Gradle sync failed: failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.1
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)"

It installed the revision then the gradle build completed. So try updating your SDK.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux(Ubuntu 16.04) you can set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable by editing the `~/.bashrc` file, by running `nano ~/.bashrc` then adding the environment variable which points to the path of your Android Sdk in my case which is `'/home/kbuhiire/Android/Sdk'` thus the environment variable looks something like this. 
`export ANDROID_HOME='/home/kbuhiire/Android/Sdk'` and after saving the file run `source ~/.bashrc`.