# Android studio SDK location not found error on mapforge

Tags: java, android-studio, mapsforge

I am trying to run the mapsforge-sample-android project but it gives me this:

```
SDK location not found. Define a location by setting the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local.properties file.
Set sdk.dir in local.properties and sync project
Affected Modules: mapsforge-map-android, mapsforge-poi-android, mapsforge-samples-android, seamap, sqlite-android, test
```

I already define the environment variable and set the sdk.dir.It gives this error only to this project.

Comment: Here is your solution. But your question sounds dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177349/sdk-location-not-found

Comment: I already did that but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS enter this command to the terminal

```
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk
```

Where `USER_NAME` is your user name on the mac