# ANDROID_HOME location not found by NativeScript

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, nativescript, android-sdk-manager

I have problem with ANDROID_HOME on a Mac OS. I'm trying to add platform android to NativeScript app and I have this message:

```
The ANDROID_HOME environment variable is not set or it points
to a non-existent directory.
You will not be able to perform any build-related operations for Android.
```

I've checked if I had SDK and yes, I have. Android Studio shows me this:

```
/Users/myuser/Library/Android/sdk
```

I found that I also have android sdk in `/usr/local/Cellar/android`

Before I have Xamarin and Homebrew which I think installs Android SKD itself. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Did you restart the terminal?

Comment: Yes, I did restart the terminal

Comment: check with `echo $ANDROID_HOME` it should print your path variable Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33631853/4936697

Comment: Yeah, I think you need to add `export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myuser/Library/Android/sdk` to your ~/.bash_profile / .profile file and restart the Terminal window.

Comment: @Eddy Varbruggen it doesnt work. Still got this error. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296237/set-android-home-environment-variable-in-mac/33631853#33631853 doenst work...

Answer (score 1):

Try this [solution](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1364):

```
npm install -g --unsafe-perm nativescript
```

It seems to be a problem with path of the `sudo`. If you use sudo with `tns` you look in sudoer `~/.basrch`, not in your user. And of course, theres not a `$ANDROID_HOME` path.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, however as a linux user.
I received a "eacces permission denied" error when i use tns run android --emulator..

I then tried sudo tns run android --emulator and the error disappeared but i got this android_home not found instead...

Subsequently i resolved by changing permissions in my Sdk, so you might want to give it a shot..

Troubleshooting Steps
1) check $ANDROID_HOME variable using echo $ANDROID_HOME and make sure it points to your Sdk folder..
- If it is not, put the path into your bash profile as others have recommended.

2) If $ANDROID_HOME is valid, check if permissions is set to read, write and execute to make sure it's not a permission issue
- I have a theory that if its a permission issue it might be because of the installation process..

Hope this helps...

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. I have valid path to SDK and all permissions :(

Answer (score 0):

Please double check that you have done the following mistake in your bash profile  :), If so please remove it.

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/bin  (no bin directory inside the Sdk)

Comment: I don't have "bin" folder in android path

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: You can't run line in terminal with "sudo"...
Without sudo ANDROID_HOME works but still emulator doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when trying to set up Svelte-native and NativeScript.
Problem was that Enviromental variables were set as administrator.

To set variables/path as user go to:
Control Panel->User Accounts->Change My Environment variables