# Google Glass App, Please select Android SDK in Edit Configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, google-glass

First, let me walk you through the process in which I am getting my error.  First, I created a successful Glass Project into Android Studio 3.0.1.  My other project will run completely, but when I run my glass app I get the error "Please select Android SDK" in Edit Configuration.  Because of this, I have tried to change the Edit Configuration with "launch default activity" and "Target USB device".  Unfortunately, this does not solve my issue.

[Here](https://www.developer.com/ws/android/creating-google-glass-applications.html) is a tutorial showing how to create and deploy a Google Glass App.

I have researched far and low regarding this issue, but every resource I have found says, to "sync gradle".  This solution does not solve my issue, nor does this work for me.

Below is an example of the "Edit Configuration" window.

[image: Edit Configuration]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: "Please select Android SDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34353220/android-studio-please-select-android-sdk)

Comment: Please read my question again.. 
"I have search lot of regarding this issue but all peoples say sync gradle but this is not my answer"

also my problem is only for glass app, for other project run successful.

Comment: Change your SDK directory to a wrong path and build it will show you an error then select again the right path and build. Issue should be resolved. I faced the issue and solved this way.

Answer (score 1):

First check <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> > <kbd>SDK Location</kbd> and ensure the path in <kbd>Android SDK location</kbd> is the correct one and matches what you have in your gradle file

(Optionally, also in the <kbd>Project Structure</kbd> window, select each module in turn, from the left hand column and make sure the android/sdk fields are correct)

You should also ensure your ANDROID_HOME environmental / system variable is set to the same SDK location. It seems you are using mac so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296237/set-android-home-environment-variable-in-mac) may help you with that.

After that you can again Clean and Sync with Gradle (as you said you tried before).

If it still fails then <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Invalidate Caches / Restart</kbd> generally resolves such problems on my system and you can also try replacing `/home/` with `~/`

Comment: Hello @Nick. I have attached screen 2 and 3, in that you can see both have same sdk path.

Comment: Hey, screen 3 is your default settings, not project structure (which may override the path). Did you try using the tilde?

Comment: Hello @Nick, I have update my question with project structure screensort.

Comment: Interesting Compile SDK. I haven't worked with glass - what happens if you change that to a regular SDK version?

Comment: If i am changing Compile SD version, i can not use Google glass component like (CardScrollView, CardScrollAdapter and CardBuilder etc) without Glass Development Kit we are not implement glass app.