# SDK location not found on Mac?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, sdk

I'm trying to run my React-native app "Android" but in every single time before i add the SDK path inside project files manually like this

**local.properties**

```
sdk.dir=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk
```

RN Error

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
>   > SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's
>   >     local properties file at
>   >     '/Volumes/..../.../.../.../android/local.properties'.

but that's tired if i want to do it in every single project i work for it

I'm Seen these [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296237/set-android-home-environment-variable-in-mac) but no one works for me

and here my `.bash_profile` => `nano ~/.bash_profile`

[image]

So What's Wrong I made?

Comment: Have tried to run `export PATH=$PATH:~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/` in your terminal ?

Comment: @KishanBharda yes  i can't see any output in the terminal and still issue happen

Comment: It does'n display any output. But worked for me.

Comment: @KishanBharda Not work sadly

Answer (score 0):

Firstly according to the error you posted, ANDROID_SDK_ROOT variable should be defined. In your bash_profile you have defined ANDROID_HOME.

Secondly verify that SDK exists in the specified path with correct rights.

Comment: Yes the path is correct, I try both `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT& ANDROID_HOME` no one works

Comment: you also have to restart the terminal for change in environment variables to take effect.

Comment: I already restart the terminal and my pc too :) but not works :(

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620262/sdk-location-not-found-define-location-with-sdk-dir-in-the-local-properties-fil), the project might be missing a settings.gradle file.
```
include ':app'
```