# Cannot download System Image for AVD

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to create a virtual device on Android Studio. I needed to download Nougat x86_64. When I started the download, it went well for the first few minutes. However, it failed more than halfway through and displayed the following message:

> To install:
>   - Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86_64)
>
> Preparing "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image".
>   Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86_64-25_r03.zip
>   An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/x86_64-25_r03.zip': Connection reset
>   , response: 200 OK.
>   "Install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image" failed.
>   Failed packages:
>   - Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image (system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86_64)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with the Nougat x86. So I downloaded it from the `.zip` link using a download manager (like DAP) that supported resume.

Then I extracted from the zip file to create an `/x86` folder under my `/downloads` folder.

Next I followed the instructions from [Android Studio SDK location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739114/android-studio-sdk-location). In my case, it was Mac OSX, so the following folder:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk
```

Under this folder, I found an empty folder named `x86`.

I moved the extracted files from the `x86` folder to the above one and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and solution was to limit internet speed from 300Mb/s to 100Mb/s, it's possible to limit from settings of netwrok card

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this as it is :-
[Android AVD Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds)

I was struggling and when I selected **Pixel 3 , 5.46** as it is same like above guide lines my **emulator launched** perfectly without any changes.
[image]