# Can't find android sdk anywhere

Tags: android, sdk

I installed android studio but as soon as i started it, an error popped up saying

> please provide a path to android sdk

i searched for it but again and again i am being redirected to ide download page only, but there's no sdk present [there](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html).

earlier android studio bundle was provided in the same link but now, only ide seems to be present in this link

i already tried getting sdk from another resources but again, no luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio SDK location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739114/android-studio-sdk-location)

Comment: True, but solutions there does'nt help

Comment: What OS are you using? Android SDK is bundled with Android Studio, so it should store it in one of the paths mentioned in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739114/android-studio-sdk-location) post.

Comment: i am using windows 10, check the link above or any other link, they will all direct you to same link which contains ide and sdk tools but i cannot find sdk

Comment: and inside my appdata\local i do not have android

Comment: Have you checked your environment variable for PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Try by uninstalling it and installing it again, or press the windows key + r and type appdata and search there for your sdk path then use that path when android studio asks you for the sdk

Answer (score 0):

Try in Settings on Android studio then type sdk and edit Android sdk location and finally chose a location, it will install a new version of sdk if there is no Android sdk on this location