# Cannot resolve symbol/method on everything but the app still builds?

Tags: android

While i was working i just restarted android studio and after the restart basically started showing "Cannot resolve symbol/method". Every single class. I already tried clean and rebuild even PC restart and nothing helps. The strange thing is that there is absolutely no problem building/running the app.[activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8qO8.png)

[image]

Comment: Test case `Invalidate cache - restart android studio`

Comment: Check that you have SDK Path set properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739114/android-studio-sdk-location

Comment: But i even restarted my PC

Comment: It would not build if the SDK wasn't set properly